# I have a pattern problem to solve!

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

The question reads:
**From the given pattern, What comes in place of '?'**

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> **(4)**.

It looks like:

> 0. Triangle from 4 figures rotates in the square anti-clockwise.
>  1. "S" goes around anti-clockwise, from one corner to another corner.
>  2. "Square" goes along main diagonal (from TopLeft to BottomRight and back).
>  3. "Triangle" goes along second diagonal (from TopRight to BottomLeft and back).
>  4. Other figures appear to chosen randomly. *May be there is some pattern I do not see, but it doesn't matter, since 2 and 4 leaves us
>  with only one possible answer, which perfectly agrees with all 5
>  patterns.*

Comment: 3 is not a distinguishing feature for the answers, because all answers have the square in the center. A distinguishing feature would be that all squares contain figures at most once. That and your 2 are sufficient to justify the answer **(4)**.

Comment: @Rhymoid, I agree on the distinguish point. I fixed it. About justification point - it is enough to mention that all figures has triangle and S signs to chose between given 4 options, but any number of patterns are not enough to fully justify any answer, induction can not be justified. Therefore it is better to have as many as possible patterns.

Comment: That's the difference between constructing answers and eliminating non-answers. Which one is better is definitely up for debate, seeing how different schools in (formal) logic are divided over a similar issue.

Comment: (3) isn't a discriminating feature, but it gives weight to (4).

Answer (score 1):

I also answer **(4)** but **I'd like to define the reason in another way**.

It appears to be *a* control structure in the patter, formed by:
a 'triangle', a 'square' and a 'S'.

This 3 signs form a triangle where:

- 'S' is in a corner and rotates anti-clockwise,
- the central vertex is 'square' or 'triangle', alternating,
- the third vertex of the triangle-structure is occupied by the
  remaining sign.

Figure number (4) is the only one validated by this pattern. (1) and (3) don't show a 'S' and in particular the (1)'s 'triangle' is not where it were supposed to be. (2) shows two 'squares' and no 'triangle', quite strange.

Comment: Keeping the 'S' criterion, and noting that the triangle cycles along the rising diagonal also limits candidates to number (4).